# How to stop increment once a certain value is reached in a JS function?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to get my increment operator to stop adding +10 after it hits 50 and I am stumped on how to establish this in my function.

```
class Vampire {
  constructor(name, otherPet){
    this.name = name;
    this.pet = otherPet || "bat";
    this.thirsty = true;
    this.ouncesDrank = 0;
  }
  drink(ouncesDrank){
    this.thirsty = false;
    this.ouncesDrank += 10;
    if(ouncesDrank >= 50){
      return 'I\'m too full to drink anymore!';
    }
  }

};
```

This is the the test file contents regarding the function:

```
it('should be full after drinking 50 ounces', function() {
    var vampire = new Vampire('Javi');

    vampire.drink();

    assert.equal(vampire.ouncesDrank, 10);

    vampire.drink();

    assert.equal(vampire.ouncesDrank, 20);

    vampire.drink();

    assert.equal(vampire.ouncesDrank, 30);

    vampire.drink();

    assert.equal(vampire.ouncesDrank, 40);

    vampire.drink();

    assert.equal(vampire.ouncesDrank, 50);

    vampire.drink();

    assert.equal(vampire.ouncesDrank, 50);

    assert.equal(vampire.drink(), 'I\'m too full to drink anymore!');
  });
});
```

This is my error message:

1 failing

1. Vampire
   should be full after drinking 50 ounces:

   AssertionError: expected 60 to equal 50

   - expected - actual

   -60
   +50

Comment: You're adding 10 before checking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *first* make the check, and only if OK, make the addition.

Secondly, you are referencing a global variable in the `if` condition, as you forgot the `this.` prefix

So change:

```
    this.ouncesDrank += 10;
    if(ouncesDrank >= 50){
      return 'I\'m too full to drink anymore!';
    }
```

to

```
    if(this.ouncesDrank >= 50){
      return 'I\'m too full to drink anymore!';
    }
    this.ouncesDrank += 10;
```

Comment: Ty for the comment. I am still getting the same error message as before even though I am now incrementing after the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing anything into the `drink` function so ouncesDrank is always undefined.

```
  drink(){
    this.thirsty = false;
    // change ouncesDrank to this.ouncesDrank
    if (this.ouncesDrank >= 50){
      return 'I\'m too full to drink anymore!';
    }
    this.ouncesDrank += 10;
  }
```